# How to stop execution after some time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, plotly-dash

I want to stop my Dash program from executing after a certain amount of time (even better when I close the browser window, though I doubt that's possible). Is there a way to interrupt it through python?

I already tried putting a

```
sys.exit()
```

after calling `app.run_server`. Though as far as I understand `app.run_server` is running code in an infinite loop, thus I'm never reaching `sys.exit()`.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.title = 'foo'
    app.run_server(debug=False)
    sys.exit("Bye!")
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since `plotly` uses `flask` for the server. So you code `sys.exit("Bye!")` is actually never reached, hence your server is never stopped. 
So there are 2 ways to stop your server,

- Ctrl + c which I assume you would be doing now
- Now you can do it using code too, so if you really need to stop the code after some time you should stop the flask server. To stop flask server you  need to create a route. So whenever you hit that url the server  would stop.

**Following is the code is for Flask, you need to transform it to equivalent plotly code:**

```
from flask import request

def shutdown_server():
    func = request.environ.get('werkzeug.server.shutdown')
    if func is None:
        raise RuntimeError('Not running with the Werkzeug Server')
    func()
```

Now you can shutdown the server by calling this function:

```
@app.route('/shutdown', methods=['POST'])
def shutdown():
    shutdown_server()
    return 'Server shutting down...'
```

**Update:** 
For plotly you can write the code in the following way.

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from flask import request

print(dcc.__version__) # 0.6.0 or above is required

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.layout = html.Div([
    # represents the URL bar, doesn't render anything
    dcc.Location(id='url', refresh=False),

    dcc.Link('Navigate to "/"', href='/'),
    html.Br(),
    dcc.Link('Navigate to "/page-2"', href='/page-2'),

    # content will be rendered in this element
    html.Div(id='page-content')
])

def shutdown():
    func = request.environ.get('werkzeug.server.shutdown')
    if func is None:
        raise RuntimeError('Not running with the Werkzeug Server')
    func()

@app.callback(dash.dependencies.Output('page-content', 'children'),
              [dash.dependencies.Input('url', 'pathname')])
def display_page(pathname):
    if pathname =='/shutdown':
        shutdown()
    return html.Div([
        html.H3('You are on page {}'.format(pathname))
    ])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, however I get the following AttributeError: 'Dash' object has no attribute 'route'

Comment: Sorry I gave you syntax for flask. You need to transform the code to plotly 
 https://dash.plot.ly/urls

Comment: @wieli99 Not sure. But I guess your first problem is solved now. you are able to shutdown the application.

Comment: Hi Guys, I am seeing an error when I use the former code to stop a dash app running on my local machine. What is this supposed to mean? And how do I find the right server it's using?? 

````
raise RuntimeError('Not running with the Werkzeug Server')
RuntimeError: Not running with the Werkzeug Server
````

Comment: When I hit insect in a browser, I see the following value 

Server: Werkzeug/2.2.2 Python/3.9.17

Despite that, hitting the /shutdown endpoint gives me an error saying "Not running with the Werkzeug Server "

Answer (score -5):

```
def button():
        button_reply = QMessageBox.question(MainWindow, "Bank Management System", "Deposited Successfully", QMessageBox.Ok)
        if button_reply == QMessageBox.Ok:
            Deposit()//execute deposite function first
            threading.Timer(5.0,clearData).start()// clrarData function will execute after 5 seconds
```

Comment: This is PyQt code, not Dash. I am guessing this account is a bot?